# How to set Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy while using Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, google-signin, cross-origin-opener-policy, sign-in-with-google

How can I resolve the 'Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy policy would block the window.closed call' error in my React application? This error seems to be related to the Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy (COOP) policy set on the server. How can I handle this error and ensure that my React app functions correctly while adhering to the COOP policy restrictions?

[image]

On searching so far I understood that I need to set

```
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: unsafe-none
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin-allow-popups
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin
```

But I don't know where and how to set.

Comment: You can only set headers on the server side

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource—when trying to get data from a REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe)

Answer (score 0):

CREATE CRACO.CONFIG.JS

module.exports = {
devServer: {
headers: {'Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy': 'require-corp', 'Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy': 'same-origin',
},
},
};

Comment: But first INSTALL CRACO.
npm install @craco/craco

Comment: and make changes in package .json
"scripts": {
  "start": "craco start",
  "build": "react-scripts build",
  "test": "react-scripts test",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject"
}

Comment: Welcome to SO! Although your answer maybe the correct one, your code is not well formated and has pieces in two other comments. You should edit all code in chronological steps (install first is ... first)  and after delete  the comments.